# Python program without console/terminal coming out

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, console, hide

Is there any way to run a Python 3 script without the terminal or the console popping out?

I tried many ways to hide the terminal at first run but even through I used .pyw extension, included a hide() function and used the --windowed flag when converting my script to an .exe through pyinstaller, the terminal still pops out for a microsecond before disappearing.

```
import win32console, win32gui
def hide():
    window = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
    win32gui.ShowWindow(window, 0)
    return True
```

I've read about a method in which you could run the python script through a C program to hide the terminal before execution but I would like to keep it as simple as I can.

Do you know any way to avoid the terminal flashing out when the script run?

Answer (score -1):

you can hide the console window by using the .pyw extension for the file